# proxy-host log from nginx is full of ":80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/"

Tags: nginx, logging, proxy

I was playing around with nginx logs and i've noticed something strange, particularly that yahoo.com as well as internet-measurement.com requests are generating this

```
....
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/:80/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
[01/Dec/2023:15:08:54 +0000] - 502 502 - GET xyz "/" [Client 34.231.60.151] [Length 556] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.1.52/] "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)" "http://www.yahoo.com"
```

Is there a way avoid this behaviour either by denying them or at least remove it from the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently accessing my domain root url directly leads to "301 Move Permantenly" and redirects to the same root url which istantiate a recursion. So for now i've solved by adding to my conf

```
location / { 
proxy_pass http://local_ip:80;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```